# Hook post-receive does not work after push from local to remote repository

Tags: git, localhost, remote-server, githooks, git-post-receive

**Description of the problem:**

I have a problem with starting the `post-receive` hook automatically in the git repository.
After made push from the local to the remote repository, hook `post-receive` just doesn't execute.

---

**Steps that I did:**

1. I create a (`non-bare`) repository on the local machine and create several commits
2. I create a repository on the remote machine (`bare`), create a `post-receive` hook there and set it to chmod to 755
3. On the local machine i add a remote repository (git remote add .....)
4. I make a push that runs correctly
5. Hook, unfortunately, does not fire

---

**My environments:**

- Local machine: `GIT 2.25.0.windows.1` @ `Win10 (1909)`
- Remote machine: `GIT 2.25.0` @ `Debian 8.11 (jessie)`

---

**Content of post-receive file at remote machine:**

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/public_html/prod --git-dir=/home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/dev.git checkout -f
```

- Note: *When I run this code directly from the ssh console, it works fine*

---

**Other SO solutions?:**

Yes, I've seen a lot, but none solve my problem. 
I've seen some answers with "unset GIT_DIR" advice, but I'm afraid it has nothing to do with it, because even just the `echo test > log.txt` does not work in `post-receive`. It looks like `post-receive` can't be started?

Comment: Is the hook in `/home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/dev.git/hooks/post-receive`?

Comment: Yes, of course, it's right there

Comment: Did you set `core.hookspath`?

Comment: You mean the setting on the remote server, right? It wasn't set. Now I've tried to set it to `core.hookspath = /home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/dev.git/hooks`. Unfortunately nothing has changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found what the problem was - the partition on the host is mounted as **`noexec`**. If so, the hooks cannot work.

This is for security reasons. It's typical situation on shared hosting.

---

#### My alternative solution:

We can create a git alias where you can run a bash script with ssh logging and run the git command directly on the server

#### How to do it?

**In the local repository configuration file we add an alias:**

```
[alias]
    run = "!sh ./hook.sh"
```

*(as you can see in the example, this alias will launch the hook.sh file)*

**Now we create a hook.sh file with git commands**

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh user@host -p [port] 'bash -s' <<-EOF
    git --work-tree=/home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/public_html/prod --git-dir=/home/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/dev.git checkout -f
    exit
EOF
```

**And now we just have to use the `git run` command**

Note: This is just a simple example. You have to test it on your envoirment!

Answer (score 0):

I know there is already an accepted response, but seems the issue comes 'cause we are trying to run with bash instead of shell I change the post-receive hooks to the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET="/dir_path/live.git"
GIT_DIR="/dir_path/project.git"

 git --work-tree=$TARGET  --git-dir=$GIT_DIR  checkout -f
```